# Derangements: Probability that exactly $r$ players get their own name.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, derangements

> Suppose $n$ competitors in a tournament organize a sweep stake on the result of the tournament. Their names are placed in an urn, and each player pays a dollar to withdraw one name from the urn. The player holding the name that wins the tournament is awarded the pot of $n$.

> (a) Show that the probability that exactly $r$ players draw their own name is $$\frac{1}{r!}\bigg\{ \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + ... + \frac{(-1)^{n-r}}{(n-r)!}\bigg\}$$

This I understand and I can derive it.

> (b) Given that exactly $r$ such matches occur, what is the probability that Fred draws his own name?

This I am struggling to answer. Fred is either part of the $r$ matches or he is not. This gives us an idea. I can condition on on Fred being part of the $r$: Let $F$ be the event that Fred draws his own name, $R$ be the event that exactly $r$ matches occur and $Q$ be the event that Fred is part of the group of matches.

$$P(F|R) = P(F|R,Q)P(Q) + P(F|R,Q^c)P(Q^c) = P(F|R,Q)P(Q)$$

I am a bit stumped here. As I have not achieved anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user2661923 gave a simple approach.  Here is an alternative approach that applies Bayes' Theorem and the result from part (a):
$$\mathbb{P}(F | R) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(R | F)\mathbb{P}(F)}{\mathbb{P}(R)} 
= \frac{\frac{1}{(r-1)!}\left(\frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \dots + \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)-(r-1)}}{((n-1)-(r-1))!}\right) \frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{r!}\left(\frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \dots + \frac{(-1)^{n-r}}{(n-r)!}\right)} = \frac{r}{n}$$

Answer (score 4):

Please advise if I am misinterpreting the problem.

You have $n$ events, of which $r$ of the events have succeeded, and $(n-r)$ events have failed.  Then, for any randomly chosen event, from the $n$ events, the probability that that event has succeeded must be

$$\frac{r}{n}.$$

Again, please advise if I am misinterpreting the question.